# How to loop over nested input forms with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html form, which is generated dynamically:

```
<ul class="precursorList">
<li>
Precursor Name: <input name="precursorName" type="text">
    <ul class="portList">
      <li>Portname of precursor: <input name="precursorPort"  type="text">
          Portname of this: <input name="thisPort"  type="text">
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>       
<li>
Precursor Name: <input name="precursorName"  type="text">
    <ul class="portList">
      <li>Portname of precursor: <input name="precursorPort"  type="text">
          Portname of this: <input name="thisPort"  type="text">
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>   
</ul>
```

I want to get the values using jquery, therefore I have defined this loop:

```
ports = [];

$(".precursorList :input").each(function() {
    if(this.name == "precursorName") {
        var precursorName_ = this.value
        $(".portList :input ").each(function() {
            if(this.name == "precursorPort") {
                precursorPort_ = this.value;
            } else if(this.name == "thisPort") {
                ports.push({
                    filterName : precursorName_,
                    portNameOfFilter : precursorPort_,
                    portNameOfThis : this.value
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this function does not work like I want it to work. The following loop `$(".portList :input ").each(` will always only loop over all elements in portList in the html document. How can I achieve that this loop will only loop over the corresponding portList, for each precursor?

**UPDATE:** The structure of the html element will stay the same only, the number of inputs will change. But there will only be a portList if a PrecursorElement exist.

Comment: Just realized if you ever hit `elseIf` block you will not have right value for `precursorPort_` as it is populated in `if` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` must be a unique field, instead use `class` to select multiple elements. Also use `.live()` for dynamically added elements.
**EDIT:**
If you are using Jquery > 1.7 use `.on()` instead of `.live()`.
I tried following and it seems that its working

```
   $(".precursorPort").each(function() {
        temp = this.name;
        $(this).parents(".portList").each(function() {
            $(this).parents(".precursorList").each(function() {
                alert(temp);
                // use temp var and save it in ports
            });
        });
    });
```

Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/DR233/
It may not be the best/most efficient but it is one of the working alternative.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated in jquery 1.7

Comment: I have changed everything to classes, I still face the problem, that the second loop loops over everything.

Comment: @tune2fs: will the HTML structure always be same ?

Comment: the overall structure will be the same but the number of elements differ.

Answer (score 0):

An `id` **must** be unique in a document. If you want to create a group of similar things, then use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
<ul id="precursorList">
<li>
Precursor Name1: <input class="precursor" name="precursorName1" id="precursorName1" type="text">
    <ul id="portList1">
      <li>Portname of precursor1: <input class="precursorPort" name="precursorPort1" id="precursorPort1" type="text">
          Portname of this1: <input class="thisPort" name="thisPort1" id="thisPort1" type="text">
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>      
<li>
Precursor Name2: <input class="precursor" name="precursorName2" id="precursorName2" type="text">
    <ul id="portList2">
      <li>Portname of precursor2 <input class="precursorPort" name="precursorPort2" id="precursorPort2" type="text">
          Portname of this2: <input class="thisPort" name="thisPort2" id="thisPort2" type="text">
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>  
</ul>
```

and then:

```
ports = [];

$("#precursorList > li").each(function()
{
    precursor = $(this).find(".precursor")[0];
    precursorPort = $(this).find(".precursorPort")[0];
    thisPort = $(this).find(".thisPort")[0];
    ports.push({filterName: precursor.value, portNameOfFilter: precursorPort.value, portNameOfThis: thisPort.value});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Step back a minute, I think you're overthinking this a bit.

Wrap your dynamic form in `<form>` tags.  Then do a `$('form').serialize()`  No need for crazy loops.  Serialize is essentially a built-in, one line version of what you're already trying to do.  Of course, serialize works on names so you'll have to have distinct ones (even if it's just name1, name2,etc)  ID's must be unique too, so either fix that or drop them.

Simplicity always trumps crazy technical genius.

[Fiddle for proof](http://jsfiddle.net/bpeterson76/ywHL6/)

Comment: I will not avoid these loops, as I need to loop over the generated string. As this is only on very simplified version what I want to do. Is it so difficult to select only the children of one <li> tag in .precursorList?

Comment: Even if it's a generated string, if you enclose it in a form tag and serialize, you'll get your values.  See the fiddle